# Vim error: Unable to open swap file when using backslash as path separator in Windows shell

Tags: microsoft-windows, swap-file

I'm using cmder as my Win7 shell. I see the following behaviour:

Works fine (file in current directory):

```
vim test
```

Works fine (absolute path):

```
vim ~/test
```

Works fine (relative path with forward slash):

```
vim subdir/test
```

Does not work fine (relative path with backward slash):

```
vim subdir\test
```

The last example flashes the following in vim:

```
E303: Unable to open swap file for "subdir\test", recovery impossible.
```

Doing `:set dir` shows:

```
directory=~/vimswap
```

which exists and is permissioned correctly (after all, I don't get errors when opening absolute path files, only relative path ones).

I suspect this might have something to do with how cmder/vim represent relative paths - maybe a forward slash/backslash issue?

Comment: I don't know anything about cmder but what does `set shellslash?` show? If you set the opposite value in your vimrc file does it help?

Comment: How does cmder deal with path separators? The screencaps on the front page of the cmder web site show ``\`` but looks like you are using `/`.

Comment: Interesting, `set shellslash` doesn't show anything. However, doing `vim subdir\test` works fine - it's the `vim subdir/test` command that fails. I think it's because windows paths use `\ `, but cmder seems to autocomplete with `/`.

Comment: Sorry, got mixed up with the slashes, I've updated the question body.

Comment: Not `:set shellslash` ... `:set shellslash?` ... you forgot the `?` and turned shellslash on. Still, try putting `set shellslash` (this time without the question mark) in your vimrc and see if it matters. I suspect not, though. I think you just can't use the version you have with `/`.

Comment: Hmm. With the Win32/console version of Vim 8.0, default settings, I can open either `foo/bar` or `foo\bar` from Windows console (cmd.exe). What happens when you use `vim -u NONE path` (where path contains either slash or backslash)?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and tracked it to the following.

I had set the following in vimrc

```
set backupdir=~/.vim/backup
set directory=~/.vim/tmp
```

But to make my work easier, I change the definition of `HOME` all the time.

When I did this, the `~` did not evaluate to a directory that had `.vim/backup` nor `.vim/tmp` in it.  Hence, I got the error.

I changed the `~` to a fixed location and the problem went away.

This was under cygwin/Windows 11

Answer (score 0):

The issue comes from Clink. A script has been submitted [on their github](https://github.com/mridgers/clink/issues/395), and Keith Milligan explains [how to apply it](https://keathmilligan.net/cmder-tip-enable-forward-slash-completion):

> Internally, cmder uses a utility called clink  to enable bash-style
> command-line completion (and other things). You can enable
> forward-slash as a path separator, but adding some additional clink
> configuration to your cmder setup. If it does not exist, create
> cmder.lua in the config directory where you installed cmder. Add the
> following code:
>
> ```
> local function force_fwd_slashes(text, first, last)
>     clink.slash_translation(1)
>     return false
> end
> clink.register_match_generator(force_fwd_slashes, -1)
> ```
>
> Save the file and restart cmder. Paths will now be completed using
> forward slashes instead of backslashes.